# how can i retrieve authenticated users information from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is my database structure

[image: this is my database structure]

i want to allow users to update their information in their profile so how can i achieve this. i know that i first need to read the information from the firebase and then deal with updating it but at the moment im having issues reading the data from the firebase.

i have attached my database structure as well as code.

```
package faz.ie.partyapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import faz.ie.partyapp.models.User;
import faz.ie.partyapp.models.updateUserInformation;

public class UserProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView image;

    private  FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private  FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private  FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private  DatabaseReference mReference;

    String userid;

    private TextView mAgeTextView;
    private TextView mGenderTextView;
    private TextView mPhoneNumberTextView;
    private TextView mFullNameTextView;
    private TextView mEmailTextView;

    private Button mEditButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.userImage);

        mAgeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.updateAgeTxt);
        mGenderTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.updateGenderTxt);
        mPhoneNumberTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.updatePhoneTxt);
        mFullNameTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.updateNameTxt);
        mEmailTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.updateEmailTxt);

        mEditButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editButton);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userid = user.getUid();

        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference usersReference = rootRef.child("userType");
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    User userInformation = new User();

                    userInformation.setEmailAddress(ds.child(userid).getValue(User.class).getEmailAddress());

                    userInformation.setFullName(ds.child(userid).getValue(User.class).getFullName());
                    userInformation.setAge(ds.child(userid).getValue(User.class).getAge());
                    userInformation.setPhoneNumber(ds.child(userid).getValue(User.class).getPhoneNumber());
                    userInformation.setGender(ds.child(userid).getValue(User.class).getGender());

                    Log.d("TAG",  userInformation.getFullName() + " / " + userInformation.getEmailAddress() + " / " + userInformation.getAge()+
                            " / " + userInformation.getPhoneNumber() + " / " + userInformation.getGender());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        usersReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

        mEditButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                // intent to go to the edit/update user information activity
            }
        });




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this, you need to change the database structure a little bit. Remove the extra node `Host a Party` and `Look for a Party` and add those types as a property of your user. Your database structure should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- users
          |
          --- uid
               |
               --- "userType": "Host a Party"
               |
               --- //the other user details
```

To display all users, just simply use the following:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String fullName = ds.child("FullName").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", fullName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

If you want to display only the users that are `looking for a party`, instead of `usersRef` you need to use the following `Query`:

```
Query query = usersRef.orderByChild("userType").equaltTo("Host a Party");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

If you want to display only the details of the authenticated user, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String fullName = dataSnapshot.child("FullName").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", fullName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Delete the old data and fresh data.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks very much for the reply. 
i think my database structure is already how u said it should be.
right now its like This:

Comment: So if your database is exactly like this, does the code above work?

Comment: the problem with having the database structure like that is that it only makes for one user right? and i have 2 types of users which are "Look for a party" user and "Host a party " user? so at the moment code does not yet work

Comment: That's why I have added that property to separate those two type of users. And I showed you also how to query the database to find each type of user.

Answer (score 0):

in :

```
 DatabaseReference usersReference = rootRef.child("userType");
```

"userType" doesn't seems to be something usable ...

Comment: How does this answer the question?